# Chaincode HLF store variables with additional info

Tags: couchdb, chaincode

i am using a hlf system based on chaincode to show how smart contracts could be created.

Now i am stuck with (in my mind) a very easy problem i guess.

I want to store a data objects content as key-value pair on the chains couchDb state database.

I am doing this with a docker request looking like this:
COMMAND WRITE: docker exec -t Lane1_Zf4URs_cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.Zf4URs.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/Zf4URs.com/orderers/orderer.Zf4URs.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.Zf4URs.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n 9bc7cca8-1dcd-49b0-a25c-fb639a0403cf -c '{"Args":["set", "[D1]{P1}", "data4"]}'

So as you see my args are calling set method and store key="[Di]{P1}" value="data4" this is working fine with this "set" method.

```
func (s *SmartContract) set(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) peer.Response {

if len(args) != 2 {

    return shim.Error("Incorrect arguments. Expecting a key and a value")

}



err := stub.PutState(args[0], []byte(args[1]))

if err != nil {

    return shim.Error("Failed to set asset: " + string(args[0]))

}

return shim.Success([]byte(args[1]))

// return args[1]
```

}

Now when looking at state dB this is the stored result:

> {
> "_id": "[D1]{P1}",
> "_rev": "2-a74269cadec50f97d34d165d60235e34",
> "~version": "8:0",
> "_attachments": {
> "valueBytes": {
> "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
> "revpos": 2,
> "digest": "md5-2cRbxPYpSEbldj1mVovx8Q==",
> "length": 5,
> "stub": true
> }
> }
> }

Now what i want to have is to store an additional value on this state db request.
Beside of "_id" (key) i want to have another field called "_executor" which should have a value "{P1}"

Should look like this:

> {
> "_id": "[D1]{P1}",
> "_rev": "2-a74269cadec50f97d34d165d60235e34",
> **"_executor": "{P1}",**
> "~version": "8:0",
> "_attachments": {
> "valueBytes": {
> "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
> "revpos": 2,
> "digest": "md5-2cRbxPYpSEbldj1mVovx8Q==",
> "length": 5,
> "stub": true
> }
> }
> }

How can i do that?
What do i have to change on the docker request or on the set method?
Is this even possible?

Many thanks for help

Comment: When trying the second option are you getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: What do you mean with the second option?

Comment: When i try to manually change the couchDB to add "_executor": "P1" i get a: Save failed: Bad special document member: _executor

Answer (score 0):

This should work!
You have no constrains on the second argument (args[1]) in your smart contract. And since this is a string it's stored in one column and hence doesn't depend on the table structure.

Comment: Ok that sounds great. So what do i have to change to additionaly store my "executor" variable?

Comment: Because executor should not be within _attachments { valueBytes }. It should be outside or at least it should be stored as real string and not as bytes

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code.
I tried to use a struct and store this.

```
`type DataObject struct {
Name string
Executor string
Data []byte} func (s *SmartContract) set(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) peer.Response {
if len(args) != 2 {
    return shim.Error("Incorrect arguments. Expecting a key and a value")
}

p := DataObject{
    Name: args[0],
    Executor: "p1",
    Data: []byte(args[1]),
}
str, err2 := json.Marshal(p)

if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println(err2)
}

fmt.Println(string(str)) 

if(args[1] == "data4"){
    err := stub.PutState(args[0], str)

    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to set asset: " + string(args[0]))
    }
    return shim.Success(str)
} else {
    err := stub.PutState(args[0], []byte(args[1]))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to set asset: " + string(args[0]))
    }

    return shim.Success([]byte(args[1]))
}}`
```

Now i can store executor but my data variable gets not stored as before. I need the digest so as before it should be _attachments: [valueBytes: ....digest:md5-xxx].

It looks like this:
[couchDb-doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ9hk.png)

> {
> "_id":       "[D1]{P1}",
> "_rev":      "1-69be87268fs88s788668f8s766fnkushof7",
> "Data":      "ZGF0YTQ=",
> "Executor":  "P1",
> "Name":      "[D1]{P1}",
> "_version":  "3:0"
> }